# Cakephp3 prefix routing for form submissions is not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am playing around with routing.  What I am wanting to achieve is URLs like "customer/customer_slug/...", so, it would be /customer/test/hosts/add or /customer/acme/networks/list.  I have set up the following routes...

```
Router::prefix('customer', function (RouteBuilder $routes){

    $routes->connect('/',['controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'index']);
//    ->setMethods(['GET','POST']);

    $routes->connect('/add',['controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'add'])
    ->setMethods(['GET','POST']);

    $routes->connect('/:slug/edit',['controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'edit'])
    ->setMethods(['GET','POST'])
    ->setPatterns(['slug'=>'[a-z0-9-_]+'])
    ->setPass(['slug']);

    $routes->connect('/:slug',['controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'overview'])
    ->setMethods(['GET','POST'])
    ->setPatterns(['slug'=>'[a-z0-9-_]+'])
    ->setPass(['slug']);

    $routes->connect('/:slug/:controller', ['action' => 'index'],['routeClass' => DashedRoute::class])
    ->setMethods(['GET','POST'])
    ->setPatterns(['slug'=>'[a-z0-9-_]+'])
    ->setPass(['slug']);

    $routes->connect('/:slug/:controller/:action', ['param'=>'slug'],['routeClass' => DashedRoute::class])
    ->setMethods(['GET','POST'])
    ->setPatterns(['slug'=>'[a-z0-9-_]+'])
    ->setPass(['slug']);

    $routes->connect('/:slug/:controller/:action/*', [],['routeClass' => DashedRoute::class])
    ->setMethods(['GET','POST'])
    ->setPatterns(['slug'=>'[a-z0-9-_]+'])
    ->setPass(['slug']); 

    // TODO:  Understand and look to remove this 
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);

});
```

I can go to URLs in my testing which is fine.  However, when I go to /customer/acme/edit, I get the edit action on the Customer/CustomersController.php and it displays the appropriate form.  Looking at the routing is debug kit, it says that it is using the following route:

```
customer:customers:edit /customer/:slug/edit    
{
    "controller": "Customers",
    "action": "edit",
    "prefix": "customer",
    "plugin": null,
    "_method": [
        "GET",
        "POST"
    ]
}
```

which is what I would expect.  However, when I submit the form, it is changing the routing to:

```
customer:_controller:_action    /customer/{controller}/{action}/*   
{
    "prefix": "customer",
    "plugin": null,
    "action": "index"
}
```

If I remove the `$routes->fallbacks(...` from the prefix section, then I get a CSRF error.

My edit page is simple

```
<?php $this->extend('../../Layout/TwitterBootstrap/dashboard'); ?>

<?php $this->start('tb_actions'); ?>
<li><?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $customer->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $customer->id), 'class' => 'nav-link']) ?></li>
<li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Customers'), ['action' => 'index'], ['class' => 'nav-link']) ?></li>

<?php $this->end(); ?>
<?php $this->assign('tb_sidebar', '<ul class="nav flex-column">' . $this->fetch('tb_actions') . '</ul>'); ?>

<div class="customers form content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($customer) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Edit Customer') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('name');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

and the associated code from the controller is

```
    public function edit($slug = null)
    {
        $customer = $this->Customers->getbySlugID($slug);

        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $customer = $this->Customers->patchEntity($customer, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Customers->save($customer)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The customer has been saved.'));

                exit;
                return $this->redirect(['controller'=>false, 'action' => 'index', $customer->slug]);

            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The customer could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('customer'));
    }
```

Looking at the URL code generated

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="form" action="/customer/customer4/edit"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"></div>    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Customer</legend>
        <div class="form-group text required"><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" required="required" maxlength="40" id="name" class="form-control" value="Customer4"></div>    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>    </form>
```

so it looks like it should be posting to the correct location (customer4 is the slug for the record).

Question is why is Cake able to get the correct route when requesting the edit page, but when it is posting, selects a different route?

NOTE:  I think there is some other routing badness as well, as if I remove the fallbacks, then my / route doesn't work.

For context, the following works fine:

/customer/add for both editing and form submission.

CakePHP version is 3.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP forms by default use (emulated) `PUT` for updating (See the hidden `_method` field in the generated form. And yes, it is debatable whether that should better be `PATCH`, but it is what it is), and you are limiting your routes to `GET` and `POST`, hence none of them will match when submitting the form, and the fallback routes will match the request instead, as they do not apply any HTTP method restrictions.

Long story short, make sure your `/edit` route accepts at least `PUT` too:

```php
$routes
    ->connect('/:slug/edit',['controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'edit'])
    ->setMethods(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT']) // <<<<<< there
    ->setPatterns(['slug'=>'[a-z0-9-_]+'])
    ->setPass(['slug']);
```

Your controller also accepts `PATCH`, which is the default created by Bake, but if you don't actually use or want to accept `PATCH` requests, then you could of course ditch that.

See also

- **[CakePHP API > \Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::create()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_create)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Did not see the PUT requirement in the docs.